# Shopify flash message after add to cart?

Tags: shopify

so currently in my Shopify store I have each item with an add to cart button which causes the user to redirect to the cart each time. I am trying to add to cart with a simple flash message to tell the user its been added so they can continue shopping without going to the cart page. I have found this for dropping redirecting...

```
<input type="hidden" name="return_to">
```

What I wanted to know is how can I then display a successful add to cart message once to the user on the page the redirect_to will go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use cart API to add product and on response, do any action.
here is the example:

```
function addItem(form_id) {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/cart/add.js',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: $('#'+form_id).serialize(),
    success: Shopify.onSuccess,
    error: Shopify.onError
  });}
```

This whole example can be found in your " Launchpad(default theme)->scripts.js.liquid " file.

Comment: What is the function of Shopify.onSuccess and Shopify.onError?

Comment: onSuccess and onError functions are defined just below ajax code OR you can define as:
    function addItem(form_id) {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/cart/add.js',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: $('#'+form_id).serialize(),
    success: function(){
//Code on Success
},
    error: function(){
//code on Erro
}
  });}